# Inno Setup script for copying folders

Tags: inno-setup

I need an Inno Setup script that copies a folder recursively.

Comment: I can't use a [Files] section because I need to check one condition before copying, and if isn't True the folder should not be copied

Comment: This comment IMHO should be edited into the original question since it modifies the question's focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Files] section entries can use a Check parameter...

Comment: But there isn't any world about this parameter in the manual about [Files] section. Thank you. Your answer helped.

Comment: True, although the help for Check parameters states "There is one optional parameter that is supported by all sections whose entries are separated into parameters...".

Comment: I can't see any relation of this answer to the question. Using `recursesubdirs` as shown in the other answer here is the way to go. [not voting down]

Comment: See the comment for the question.

Answer (score 51):

Just use `Flags: recursesubdirs`

```
[Files]
DestDir: {app}; Source: Files\*; Excludes: "*.m,.svn,private"; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

If you need to exclude something, add `Excludes` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I've finished this project a month ago and my customer is very happy :)

Comment: This fails if the folder is empty